# rails4 postgres default_function now()

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

`t.timestamp :time, default_function: "current_timestamp"`
this is setting no value at all to time.

Whats the correct way of setting the default_timestamp for new records by postgres?

Using `default: "now()"` works in mysql, but in postgres then its the date when we created the table

---

*edit*

`execute('ALTER TABLE "user_visits" ADD COLUMN "time" timestamp without time zone DEFAULT CURRENT_DATE')`

this is working - but there must be a rails way, right?